# How to avoid repetition of selector names in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and Javascript and I wonder if there's a shorter way to write this:

```
function setSearchForm() {
  if ($('#search input[type=text]').val().length != 0) {
    $('#search input[type=submit]').removeProp('disabled');
    $('#search #clear_button').show();
  } else {
    $('#search input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#search #clear_button').hide();
  }
}
```

The repetition of the `#search` selector feels clumsy to me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There probably is :

```
function setSearchForm() {
    var s = $('#search'), l = !$('input[type=text]',s).val().length;
    $('input[type=submit]',s).prop('disabled',l)
    $('#clear_button',s).toggle(!l);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PdCxZ/)

Comment: That's indeed very short! Thank you very much. And thanks to everybody else too.

Comment: I would recommend making the code more readable. It's important in any situation, but particular given that the OP is new to js and jQuery. Let the minifier/obfuscator worry about making the source compact.

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE - the question wasn't how to make it more readable, but how to make it shorter, and it's perfectly readable to me ?

Comment: Each to their own :) I just don't think other members of a team would thank you for source code that was formatted like this

Comment: If the other members of said team knows how to read code, they'd be thrilled I managed to get such a basic function down to just a few lines. On the other hand, if they have no idea what they are doing, a large number of comments and / or a really simple condition etc. would probably be better !

Answer (score 2):

One thing is that since `#clear_button` already has an ID, you don't need to reference `#search` there.   So a quick code cleanup is here:

```
function setSearchForm() {
  if ($('#search input[type=text]').val().length != 0) {
    $('#search input[type=submit]').removeProp('disabled');
    $('#clear_button').show();
  } else {
    $('#search input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#clear_button').hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Also it's not necessarily the case that removing the qualifier will result in the same behavior. That is, the original code may explicitly only want to affect the "clear_button" element when it's a child of the "search" element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I completely disagree.   The OP wanted less occurrences of the #search ID.   I provided code that accomplished that, as well as giving a suggestion regarding how to reference IDs.

Comment: @Pointy while that is technically true...  an ID should never be used more than once on a page.

Comment: Yes but that's not what I mean. It could be that sometimes the "clear_button" appears on the page inside the "search" container, and sometimes it doesn't. Probably that's splitting hairs a little too thinly however :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not use `removeProp`, removing property of an element can cause undesired behavior. But for your question you can write it as:

```
var $search = $('#search');
function setSearchForm() {
    $search.find('#clear_button').toggle();
    $search.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !$search.find('input[type=text]').val().length);
}
```

Just use prop and set the flag to disable it or not. Excerpt from the [official doc](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

> With some built-in properties of a DOM element or window object, browsers may generate an error if an attempt is made to remove the property. jQuery first assigns the value undefined to the property and ignores any error the browser generates. In general, it is only necessary to remove custom properties that have been set on an object, and not built-in (native) properties.
>
> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Since you are using ids and which must be unique, you can do this way as well

```
//cache this outside since this is gng to be unique and to avoid creating the object over and again
var $search = $('#search'), $clear = $('#clear_button'); 
function setSearchForm() {
    $clear.toggle();
    $search.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !$search.find('input[type=text]').val().length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign selector to a variable i.e cache the selector and use it where ever you want.

```
var s_s = $('#search input[type=submit]');
var s_t = $('#search input[type=text]');
var s_c = $('#search #clear_button');

function setSearchForm() {
    s_s.prop('disabled', !s_t.val().length);
    s_c.toggle();
}
```

Comment: what about `$('#search input[type=submit]')` ?

Comment: @Ram please read again `s_t.prop('disabled', !s_t.val().length);`

Comment: var s_t = $('#search input[type=text]') but i can't find `$('#search input[type=submit]')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var search = $('#search'),
      submit = search.find('input[type=submit]'),
      textInput = search.find('input[type=text]'),
      clear = $('#clear_button');

  setSearchForm = function(){
      if (textInput.val().length != 0) {
          submit.removeProp('disabled');
          clear.show();
      } else {
          submit.prop('disabled', true);
          clear.hide();
      }
  }


});
```

Though I would recommend you don't pollute the global namespace with the `setSearchForm` function